# how to create a one parameter constructor that calls a three parameter constructer

Tags: java, constructor

create a one
parameter constructor that initializes the 
year
 variable 
while setting the 
day
and
month
variables 
to 
1. 
This   constructor   MUST   call   the   three-
parameter 
constructor
.

```
 //constructor one
 public MyDate(int year){
  // this is what I have so far for the first constructor but it doesnt seem to be correct.
   this.day = 1;
   this.month = 1;
 // call for the three parameter constructor .
   MyDate myDate = new MyDate ( day=1 , month=1, year);
  }

  // constructor two
  public MyDate(int day, int month, int year){
  ........
  }


  public static void main(String[] args){   
    //Check whether a user input advances correctly
    java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a date to advance, in format day month year: ");
    int year,month,day;       
    day = scan.nextInt();
    month = scan.nextInt();
    year = scan.nextInt();
    MyDate date = new MyDate(day, month, year);

    System.out.println("Entered date is "+ date);


    MyDate correctDate;

    //TC 1 : one parameter constructor. 
    // not passing this test

    date = new MyDate(2013);
    correctDate = new MyDate(1,1,2013);
    if (date.equals(correctDate))
        System.out.println("TC 1 passed");
    else
        System.out.println("TC 1 failed");  

   }
```

Comment: That code shouldn't even compile. Also, you need to work on your communication skills. You can't just write the task and a bunch of code and toss it on SO like that. We're not robots here. Java doesn't have named parameters, so you can't write `day=1` as parameter. You have to choose one or the other.

Comment: so how would i set the day and month equal to one?

Answer (score 1):

Your date class is worse than the existing stuff.  You should be using `java.time` package.

But if you must:

```
public class MyDate {

    private final int year;
    private final int month;
    private final int day;

    public MyDate(int y) {
        this(y, 1, 1);
    }

    public MyDate(int y, int m, ind d) {
        this.year = y;
        this.month = m;
        this.day = d;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer that you vote the answer up and accept it to your thanks.  Do look at the JDK date classes.  They are far better than yours.